# Why am I getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in spite of initializing the array with a size

Tags: android, arrays, adapter

I'm unable to find out why am I getting this exception despite initializing the array with a size. When I try to increase the size of the array this exception occurs.Here is my code. Can anybody suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
public class MsgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public String msgs[]=new String[150];
public Activity context;  
public LayoutInflater inflater;
int count=16;
public MsgAdapter(Activity context,String[] msgs) {  
    super();  

    this.context = context;  
    this.msgs = msgs;  


    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
} 
public static class ViewHolder  
{  

    TextView msgView;  

ImageView b;
}  
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("count", ""+msgs.length);
    return msgs.length+16;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      final ViewHolder holder; 

        View v;  

         LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater(); 
         if(convertView==null){
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_list, null);
              holder = new ViewHolder();
              holder.msgView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgtext);
             holder.b=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms); 
                convertView.setTag(holder);  
         }
         else  
            {
                holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  

             }  
         holder.b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",     holder.msgView.getText().toString());
                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);       
            }
        });

        holder.msgView.setText(msgs[position]);//the exception occurs here
return convertView; 
}
}
```

Comment: Your program is requesting you that you should learn about ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, that why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use `ArrayList<String> msg` instead of using `String []msg`, because the size of ArrayList can be dynamically increased and decreased.

There is another bug (may be.)

you initialize your array in `MsgAdapter` like this.

```
public String msgs[]=new String[150];
```

and now you set another `String` array to `msgs` again here.

```
public MsgAdapter(Activity context,String[] msgs) {  
    ... 
    this.msgs = msgs;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problem. ArrayList<String> is far more efficient than String[].

Answer (score 0):

In `getCount()` method you are returning size of list `msgs.length+16` . Therefore `getView()` method of adapter will be called more than value of msgs.length and this line

```
holder.msgView.setText(msgs[position]);
```

will throw exception when value of position is more that or equal to `msgs.length` .

Answer (score 0):

exception is most probably on the line:

holder.msgView.setText(msgs[position]);

and its beczuse you are returning in getCount is msg.length+18, but array msg is still of length msg.length, hope its clear nw